# Comparison between Twitter Bootstrap Gems for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, comparison, twitter-bootstrap

What are the advantages and/or disadvantages of the different gems providing Twitter Bootstrap's functionality to Rails? As of the time of writing this question, The Ruby Toolbox [lists the following projects](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=twitter+bootstrap):

- [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/twitter-bootstrap-rails)
- [bootstrap-sass](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/bootstrap-sass)
- [bootstrap_form](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/bootstrap_form)
- [less-rails-bootstrap](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/less-rails-bootstrap)
- [anjlab-bootstrap-rails](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/anjlab-bootstrap-rails)
- [compass_twitter_bootstrap](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/compass_twitter_bootstrap)
- [bootstrapped-rails](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/bootstrapped-rails)
- [bootstrap-sass-rails](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/bootstrap-sass-rails)
- [bootstrap-generators](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/bootstrap-generators)
- [css-bootstrap-rails](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/css-bootstrap-rails)
- [twitter-bootstrap-markup-rails](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/twitter-bootstrap-markup-rails)
- [fennec](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/fennec)
- [bootstrap-rails](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/bootstrap-rails)
- [compass-bootstrap](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/compass-bootstrap)
- [bootstrapped](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/bootstrapped)

And even some others providing partial functionality (e.g. generating forms). How do these gems differ?

P.S. If appropriate, please write about each gem in a separate answer, so that each one can be voted for.

Comment: See also [Rails Tutorial -Bootstrap and Custom CSS](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout?version=4.0#sec-custom_css) (Uses **bootstrap-sass**), http://railsapps.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-rails.html (They recommend **bootstrap-sass**), and http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics (He uses **twitter-bootstrap-rails**). I personally use **bootstrap-sass** and like it.

Answer (score 11):

The gems use various ways of getting twitter bootstrap into your Rails app.

Quoted from an excellent blog post on the topic, [Twitter Bootstrap, Less, and Sass: Understanding Your Options for Rails 3.1](http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/):

> - Using the original Less code via a Rails engine (less-rails-bootstrap or twitter-bootstrap-rails)
> - Copying in translated Sass code directly into your application (sass-twitter-bootstrap), or
> - Using a translated Sass version via a Rails engine (bootstrap-sass or bootstrap-rails).

Deciding which kind of approach you feel best about, will help you decide what gem to use.

Answer (score 3):

I use anjlab-bootstrap-rails.

- It has these benefits: Its development is very active.
- They released the 3rd version recently which includes the latest twitter bootstrap 3.
- It also works with rails4.
- One important aspect of bootstrap3 was that the icons were migrated from .png to font files which is great.

In general I am pleased with it.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the ***anjlab-bootstrap-rails***, because I've wanted to start a new prototype project with **Bootstrap 3.0 RC1** and **Rails 4**.

I had some issues with turbolinks and the bootstrap javascript not working for dropdown component, used in the navbar.

After some search and some debugging, I could make it work *moving the javascript include tag to head section* of the html layout page.

A plus for this gem, is that it doesn't include the icons and you can choose any set you wish, like glyphicons or awesome-font, for example.

Comment: Are you still using this gem?

Comment: Yes, I still use it. It now works flawless. In my project, I use these two gems:

`gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-glyphicons'`